# Titanium SDK zip package is not being generated

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I downloaded the Titanium SDK and followed the steps to locally build it from [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Building_the_Titanium_SDK_From_Source).

According to the guide, they changed the way to build the SDK to the one listed in [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/README.md#building-locally).

But when I try to perform the build like this:

> node scons.js build --android-ndk c:\Android\android-ndk-r9
> --android-sdk c:\Android\SDK

The console shows the following lines of text:

> Building MobileSDK version 6.1.0, githash 591555a You don't seem to
> have the appropriate thirdparty files. I'll fetch them. This could
> take awhile.. Might want to grab a cup of Joe or make fun of Nolan.
> Downloading
> http://timobile.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/libTiCore-24.a.gz
> 100% [========================================] 0.0s
>
> Gunzipping C:\Users\AGUSTN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\117215-10132-d88fho.gz
> to C:\Titanium\titanium_mobile\iphone\lib\libTiCore.a

And it stops there, when I go check the dist folder no zip is found.

Why is the zip not being generated and no error being thrown?

I have the following enviroment variables set:

- ANDROID_SDK
- ANDROID_NDK
- PATH with the paths to THE BINARIES for NPM (3.83), Node.js (5.10.1),
  git (2.8.1.windows.1), Python (2.7.13), Java (8 rev 77), Ant (1.9.7),
  gperf (3.0.1), $ANDORID_SDK/platform-tools and $ANDROID_SDK/tools
- JAVA_HOME (Java 8 rev 77)
- ANDROID_PLATFORM (set to 17)
- GOOGLE_APIS (set to 23)

Why is the SDK not being packaged?

Comment: Did you install the node `titanium` and `appc` node package? If you have the android-ndk and sdk path in your PATH variable you don't need the parameters in the node call. So just `node scons.js build` and `node scons.js package` to create the zip file should be enough.

Comment: no, I don't recall seeing them mentioned, did I miss them in some part of the guide? What is the correct way to install them? Also I added the paths in the build cuz I thought maybe there was a problem with the Android paths.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if you need them to build the SDK but I would give it a try. `npm install titanium appc -g` (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Setting_up_the_Titanium_CLI)

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe it was that easy, please put your answer cuz it made me realize my mistake

Comment: Glad it worked! Posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the node tools `titanium` and `appc` with:

`npm install titanium appc -g`

in order to compile the SDK